# How can i disable the TABs being removed in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I make a "TAB" character in Visual Studio Code and Save after this, all TABS which do not have something written afterwards will get deleted. Also when I am writing a TAB and switch to another line writing something it will delete the TAB i wrote in another line before. Is it possible to disable the TABs getting removed? I am really annoyed by it...

Comment: Set this to false: `editor.trimAutoWhitespace`  Search for "Trim Auto Whitespace" in settings, uncheck it (same as setting the value above to false.  And same with `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false` (the default for this is false).

Comment: @Mark thank you very much it does not delete on save anymore but sadly i can not find `editor.trimAutoWhitespace` in the `settings.json` file. So it still removes TABs when I switch the line.

Comment: @Mark I found the reason I did not found it. Because `"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true` is the default setting it is not written in the `settings.json` file so one has to write it in the end themself or do it in the Prefferences (Settings->Texteditor->Trim Auto Whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

4 years late but I Found something:

In your settings search for "Trim Auto Whitespace" and change it to off.